# Unable to retrieve custom list value from saved search in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Creating saved search in suitescript using nlapiSearchRecord. All the column value returns except one column which is type is custom list.
How could I get value of custom list?

To get the value I'm using code lines below.

```
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn( 'customlist' );
 var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord( 'customrecord', null, filters, columns );
```

To get the column value

```
var  listValue = searchresult.getListValue( 'customlist' );
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've simplified your code in trying to be clear or confidential but there will never be fields or records with those ids.

from a search you would do:

```
var searchResult = searchResults[0];
searchResult.getValue(fieldId, joinName, summary)
// or in your case
searchResult.getValue('customlist'); //returns id of list value or simple result of non-list/record fields
```

or (and I think this is the one you want)

```
searchResult.getText('customlist'); // returns the display value of the list/record field.
```

Comment: Yea exactly I would like to  get value of  list/record field.  As you mentioned  I'm using  searchResult.getValue(customlist). But from search result  it doesn't return anything.

Comment: If you are still having trouble look at the edited code sample